# Is it possible to create or send my own custom command to work on ftp server

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, filezilla, ftp4j

I am creating a Android client which successfully uploads a file to my ftp server.
I am using ftp4j library and want to send my custom command like this.
e.g

mycustomcommand is a kind of tcp command..

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    try {

        client.connect(FTP_HOST, 21);
        client.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
        client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);

        client.changeDirectory("/Test/Uploads/");

        client.upload(fileName, new MyTransferListener());

        /**
         * Need help in this
         */
        FTPReply reply = client.sendCustomCommand("mycustomcommand");
        Log.e(TAG,"reply="+reply.toString() );

    }
```

Is it possible to do so using ftp or may be I need to use some another method like sockets..?

I just want to perform the action on server side based on mycustomcommand like upload or delete or rename..

Comment: This can be done using FTP. But that means you will have to implement this command in your FTP server. Did you write the FTP server code yourself as wel?

Comment: what is this 'mycustomcommand'? Is it something your FTP server natively understands?

Comment: @Fortega Means is it possible that I can create a custom script on ftp server which understand my custom command to perform any operation?

Comment: @Fortega can you be more clear about how I can write FTP server code and publish to FTP server using FileZila?

Comment: @SergeyA mycustomcommand is a string like "3212ZZ5y.mp3" ..based on 32 code the file should be uploaded on ftp ...In short I need to upload y.mp3 file by sending this command  from Android client.

Comment: @user3138859 It depends on which ftp server you are using. Most of them have some kind of 'plugin' system to create your own commands